# Unable to locate package python3-bluez

Tags: python, bluez, openhab

I'm stuck at the installation process for openhabian , I realized I couldn't get package python3-bluez to install. 
script ran :

```
    needed_packages() {
  # Install apt-transport-https - update packages through https repository
  # Install bc + sysstat - needed for FireMotD
  # Install avahi-daemon - hostname based discovery on local networks
  # Install python/python3-pip - for python packages
  echo -n "$(timestamp) [openHABian] Installing additional needed packages... "
  if cond_redirect apt-get -y install apt-transport-https bc sysstat avahi-daemon python3 python3-pip avahi-autoipd fontconfig; then echo "OK"; else echo "FAILED"; exit 1; fi

  if is_pithree || is_pithreeplus || is_pizerow; then
    echo -n "$(timestamp) [openHABian] Installing additional bluetooth packages... "
    if cond_redirect apt-get -y install bluez python3-bluez python3-dev libbluetooth-dev raspberrypi-sys-mods pi-bluetooth; then echo "OK"; else echo "FAILED"; exit 1; fi
  fi
}
```

Couldn't really find what's wrong, the rest of the packages : bluez python3-dev libbluetooth-dev raspberrypi-sys-mods pi-bluetooth were installed successfully. When I ran python -V it shows 2.7.13. 
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You may have better luck posting your question as an issue on the [**openhabian** GitHub site](https://github.com/openhab/openhabian/issues).

Comment: python3-bluez is available i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package you've asked about - `python3-bluez` is available in the current package repository (buster). This may be verified as follows:

```
$ apt-cache search python3-bluez
python3-bluez - Python 3 wrappers around BlueZ for rapid bluetooth development
```

If it can't be found in `openhabian`, then the problem is with `openhabian`, and you will have to [submit the issue to them](https://github.com/openhab/openhabian/issues) for resolution.

Wrt your comment/observation re `python -V`; I get something different on my system (Raspbian Buster):

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.16
```

In Raspbian, Python ver 3 is known as `python3` rather than `python`:

```
$ python3 -V
Python 3.7.3
```